# How to find the default value of variables (e.g., \columnsep)

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I want to use the value of `\columnsep` but I can not find what was the default value.

Comment: Add \the\columnsep to your document, then the value is printed. Or Use \showthe\columnsep to see it on the terminal and get it in the log.

Comment: Good comment, Ulrike. Very useful peace of information indeed.  I have tried myself, but noted that putting `\the` before a command shows the current value. It will show the default one if no value was assigned manually or modified by a package option or the like.

Comment: all length registers start out set to 0pt, then have a current value set in the format or a package or document code, the previous values are not recorded, so the default ion that sense is always 0pt.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh If you want to keep the original value you will have to store it before changing it.

Comment: Also, the default value depends on the document class, which package was loaded last, and often what environment you are in.